# Is the usage of "il" vs "lo" and "i" vs "gli" aligned?

Tags: articles

Previously I asked someone and they confirmed that the usage of "un/uno" is aligned with "il/lo", both use the O version before a noun that starts with S + a consonant or Z or PS.

However some told me that there are cases where you use *il* for a singular noun but *gli* for its plural form. I have forgot the details.

Are all nouns that use *il* as their singular article use *i* as their plural article? If not, is there a word that you would say *il something* and at the same time *gli somethings*?

Comment: Off the cuff, only the very irregular _il dio_ - _gli dei_ comes to my mind, but I might well miss other cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're aligned, except for one case that's [mentioned by DaG](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9919/is-the-usage-of-il-vs-lo-and-i-vs-gli-aligned#comment22108_9919): **il dio / gli dei**   as stated in the book [*L'italiano for dummies*](https://books.google.it/books?id=8j2qBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT176&lpg=PT176&dq=%22il+dio%22+%22gli+dei%22+articolo+unica+eccezione&source=bl&ots=lFfGsOQ0ef&sig=pJBFBOLUL-K7zHddT8mux0UjFa0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjInZOxo-fdAhWmiIsKHS82BS0Q6AEwBnoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22il%20dio%22%20%22gli%20dei%22%20articolo%20unica%20eccezione&f=false) by  Antonio Zoppetti:

> Tutto chiaro? E allora che "gli dei" fulminino chi dovesse ancora sbagliare! Non vi siete accorti di nulla? Si vede che state andando a orecchio, invece di aver digerito le regole, altrimenti avreste notato subito che *il dio* al plurale diventa *gli dei*, non "i dei", ma questa violazione di quanto esposto sino a qui non è che l'unica eccezione che conferma la regola.

One uses **lo** (**l'**) or **gli** before a masculine noun if it begins with *s + consonant*, *z-*, *ps-* or *gn-*. For example:

- lo stesso / gli stessi, lo zitto / gli zitti, lo psicologo / gli psicologi, lo gnocco / gli gnocchi, l'amico / gli amici

Comment: Here you can find a [reference about this](https://it.wikiversity.org/wiki/L%27Articolo_(superiori)).

Comment: Abbiamo una fonte non-wiki da cui risulti che dio/dei è l'unica eccezione?

Comment: @DaG Non lo abbiamo, ma non penso che c'è un altro (o non lo trovo almeno).

Comment: Ma se non abbiamo una fonte, come sappiamo che è vero? (Come sai le wiki non sono fonti, e anzi dovrebbero citare le fonti di tutto quello che riportano.)

Comment: @DaG Forse potremmo assumere che è vero perché nessuno dice che è sbagliato?

Comment: @DaG Ma quando tutti i risultati sulla ricerca di Google dicono che non c'è eccezione, come potremmo dire che ci sarebbero le eccezioni?

Comment: @iBug: No, certo, in assenza di una fonte attendibile non possiamo dire né una cosa né il suo contrario. Se fra quello che hai trovato con Google c'è qualcosa di affidabile (una risposta della Crusca, una pubblicazione scientifica, una citazione da un libro), inseriamolo senz'altro.

Comment: @DaG: Se ne parla nella sezione IV.13 dell'*Italiano* di Serianni. Non si dice in modo esplicito che si tratti dell'unica eccezione ma non vedo che nel libro ne appaia nessun'altra. (Hai ragione però nel fatto che i wiki non sono una buona fonte).

Comment: @Charo: Ho trovato [qui](https://books.google.it/books?id=8j2qBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT176&lpg=PT176&dq=%22il+dio%22+%22gli+dei%22+articolo+unica+eccezione&source=bl&ots=lFfGsOQ0ef&sig=pJBFBOLUL-K7zHddT8mux0UjFa0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjInZOxo-fdAhWmiIsKHS82BS0Q6AEwBnoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22il%20dio%22%20%22gli%20dei%22%20articolo%20unica%20eccezione&f=false) un possibile riferimento in un vero libro (ancorché “for Dummies”) di un autore che si occupa di lingua italiana.

Comment: Bene, @DaG, ma io non posso visualizzare niente di questo libro.

Comment: @DaG: Cambiando il navigatore Internet ho finalmente potuto visualizzare qualcosa.