# Perché è "il dio" ma è "gli dei" nella forma plurale?

Tags: grammar, etymology

In [this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9919/4814) [DaG mentioned](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9919/is-the-usage-of-il-vs-lo-and-i-vs-gli-aligned#comment22108_9919) that the plural form and article of the word *il dio* are *gli dei* instead of *i dei*.

Why is the word *dio* special? How did it become special?

---

In [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9919/4814) [DaG citava](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9919/is-the-usage-of-il-vs-lo-and-i-vs-gli-aligned#comment22108_9919) che la forma plurale e l'articolo della parola *il dio* sono *gli dei* anziché *i dei*.

Vorrei sapere la ragione dell'articolo *gli* davanti alla parole *dei*.

Comment: Here it is an [article of Accademia della Crusca](http://nencioni.sns.it/fileadmin/template/allegati/QuesitiRisposte/2000_20/2000_20_Risposta_13.pdf) about this subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this in "[Si dice o non si dice](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/D/dei-gli-dei.shtml)" by Hoepli Editore:

> **DÈI: PERCHÉ GLI DÈI E NON I DÈI?**
>
> Diciamo *i deboli*, *i devoti*, *i
> deserti*; ma perché allora *gli dèi* e non *i dèi*?
>
> C’è nella nostra lingua
> la forma *Iddio* nata anticamente da *il Dio*, dove l’articolo s’è fuso
> col nome. La parola si scriveva anche con la *i* minuscola quando
> riferita alle divinità pagane: *iddio* con plurale *iddíi* e anche *iddei*.
> Di queste varie forme, solo *Iddio* con la maiuscola è ancora vivo
> nell’uso comune.
>
> Tutto questo spiega la ragione dell’articolo *gli*
> anziché *i* davanti a dei: perché anticamente la parola era *iddei*:
> dunque *gli iddei*, come *gli ideali*, *gli idranti*, *gli idiomi* eccetera
> (vedi alla voce [il oppure lo?](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/I/il-lo.shtml)). Ma caduto il gruppo iniziale *id*,
> l’articolo *gli* ha pensato bene di rimanere abusivamente al suo posto e
> non cederlo ad un *i* che sarebbe grammaticalmente più corretto.
> Ennesima dimostrazione che la lingua non la fanno i grammatici ma
> l’uso (e a volte il sopruso).

And its approximate translation is the following:

> We say *i deboli*, *i devoti*, *i deserti* but why then *gli dèi* and
> not *i dèi*?
>
> In our language there is the form *Iddio* coming from the ancient *il
> Dio*, where the article fused with the name. The word was written also with
> the lowercase when referring to pagan deities: *iddio* with the
> plural *iddii* and also *iddei*.  Of these various forms, only *Iddio*
> with the capital letter is still alive in current usage.
>
> This explains the reason of the article *gli* instead of *i* before dei: because in the past the word was *iddei*, the same as *gli ideali*, *gli idranti*, *gli idiomi* etc. (take a look to the [il oppure lo?](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/I/il-lo.shtml) (dictionary) entry). But after the dropping of the initial group *id-*, the article *gli* decided to stay illegally without giving up its place to an *i* which would be more grammatically correct.
> Further demonstration that language is not made by grammarians but by the usage (and sometimes the abuse).

Moreover, as mentioned by @Charo, there is an interesting and more extensive [article by Accademia della Crusca](http://nencioni.sns.it/fileadmin/template/allegati/QuesitiRisposte/2000_20/2000_20_Risposta_13.pdf) answering your question.

Comment: Since the question is in English, may you please add an explanation in this language?

Comment: Just a minute... :))

Comment: Good catch. È una risposta perfetta.

Comment: I think @DaG should/could check my translation about correctness...

Comment: @abarisone I'm not DaG, but I took the liberty to make the English a bit more idiomatic. Feel free to revert if you feel I overstepped

Comment: Very good improvements! That’s what was needed.